# Any alternative for statsd?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, go, statsd

I have my application installed on GAE (written in go lang).How can i measure my custom metric  real time.Is there any alternative for statsd for realtime  logging?

ps : I cant have statsd client on GAE because its not supported.

Comment: You can do it using Redis, but you'll need to write the logic yourself or use a library for it

Comment: It depends on what your use case is. You can use something like the ELK stack to send your logs to elasticsearch (elastic) and use Kibana. However, I find it surprising that you cant use the statsd client on GAE?

Comment: Yeah we can't use statsd client on GAE. GAE don't support external  packages other than Google cloud packages. @MrWillihog